# Path variables on Linux and Windows

Tags: java, windows, linux, path

I had several path variables in a Java project, that worked fine on Linux. These variables are stored in the `.properties` file and are used in Spring application context. Here is an example of a name variable that works: `just.an.example=/home/username/settings/`. Pretty straightforward, right? I'm trying to run this app on Windows machine. I tried the following: `just.an.example=d:/settings/`, `just.an.example=d\:/settings/`, `just.an.example=d\:\\settings\\`, `just.an.example=file:///d:/settings/` and a few more, none of which worked.

I get NullPointerException that is a reason of an attempt to use files taken from the folder (which made me think the folder can not be seen). To be more specific, these variables are used as parameters of the `File` class constructor. The rights to access folders are default, I just created them.

What is a working option for this example variable?

**Update**: It finally worked with `just.an.example=D:/settings/`, somehow I had to reimport Maven project after reinstalling it, not only to update dependencies, but `D:/settings/` works fine in this case.

Comment: Try D:\\Settings\\ - See the special characters and escaping section here - http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html

Comment: Basically d:/settings/ should work just fine, usually restarting the computer helps.

Comment: @ftom2 Well, no, this probably shouldn't work. And how is it related to restarting?

Comment: @verisimilitude That was promising, but didn't work.

Comment: What i meant by 'should work' is that this is the way to define an environment variable on windows. And when defining environemnt variables on windows that are used by Java program, it sometimes takes a restart of the computer after the variables where defined in order for the java program to recognize it (only one restart after definition/update)

Comment: umm, have you tried d:\settings\? it's a properties file, there should be no need to escape '\'

Comment: BTW, You only need to use special chars if you define those variable though code, if you define it manually (my computer->properties) or in a properties file,then you can write it as i mentioned.

Comment: You could be more specific in your question. What's the specific error message that you get? does the directory really exist? Did you check if the running program has the appropriate read permission on the directory?

Comment: @ftom2 Oh, I see, it's a good point, but these are not the environment variables.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy Thanks, it didn't help, but it's a useful comment about escaping characters.

Comment: Could you post more details about the exception and where in the code it happens?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy Sorry, I don't think I can post the code, as I said it's a File constructor (the object contains a directory in this case) and it works on Linux.

Comment: the only way I see you getting an NPE is that whatever you get from the property file is null. post at least a stacktrace, my libastral power is depleting.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy Haha, well, look, stacktrace would be a bit boring to read. Here is what happens: the object need to be instantiated with the `new File(path)`, then with `listFiles()` I get files, but I get nothing as soon as the directory instance isn't created just the right way (with the path I asked about), so I get NPE later when I try to use files (that were supposed to appear after the `listFiles()` usage).

Comment: what do new File(path).exists() or .isDirectory() return?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy False both times, the code after that instantiation doesn't get executed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/home/username/settings/` is equivalent to `D:/settings/`, the last would be correct. Forward slashes work fine for this and I have done this type of thing many times. If you can access `D:/settings/` through Windows explorer, then Java should also be able to. Try pasting `D:/settings/` in Windows explorer and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, well, I know it should, but it doesn't work. I'll try to find out the reason under the debug.